# How do I add support for a LSP server in ALE that is not already supported?

Tags: lsp

I want to add support for an LSP server for ALE in my local configuration. It's not supported by default.

I can see how supported-by-default servers are done, e.g. https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/tree/master/ale_linters/openscad, but how do I do this in my local configuration?

Can anyone provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: [Doc link](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/doc/ale.txt#L215).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can see from [`:help ale-lint-language-servers`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/9fe9f115213d7e7bf52d06ebdc69c6df38b1120b/doc/ale.txt#L215) that

> New linters can be defined in |vimrc|,
> in plugin files, or `ale_linters` directories in |runtimepath|.

So if you are comfortable with the stuff in the `openscad` files you linked, you can do the same thing locally in `~/.vim/ale_linters`.